# Display: inline-block not working with divs

Tags: html, css, block, display

i'm trying to create a news box where there will be a div containing an image on the left and a div containing lines of text on the right. Whenever i set them to inline-block the text goes right beneath the div image and stays there. I want them to be in a single line.
Here's my code, can you point out what i'm doing wrong?

EDIT: Corrected the TYPO but still...

```
<div id="newsBox">

        <div id="newsImg">
            <img src="images/news1.jpg" alt="news1">
        </div>

        <div class="metaNews">
            <div id="newsTitle">
                <h3>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text .</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="newsBrief">
                <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>

        <div class="newsBy">
            <span class="metaDate">Posted on 10/5/2017</span>
            <span class="metaBy">By Li</span>
        </div>

        <div class="newsLink">
            <a href="news1.html">View &rarr;</a>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>

</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#newsBox {
    width: 85%;
    margin: 0.5rem auto;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    border: #333 solid 1px;
    background-color: #c2c2c2;
}

#newsImg {
    display:inline-block;

    
}
#newsImg > img{
    max-width:  120px;
    max-height: 120px;
    padding-right:20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.metaNews{
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    
}
#newsTitle {

}
.newsBy {
    display:inline-block;
}
.newsLink {
    float:right;
    width: 6rem;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #2F4F4F; 
}
.newsLink a{
    font-family: 'Play', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: To start there is a spelling mistake, you have written `display:inline-blockl`

Comment: Corrected that but still.

Answer (score 1):

You got a typo in:

```
.metaNews{
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-blockl

}
```

`inline-blockl` has extra `l` instead of a `;`

```
.metaNews{
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;

}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ow5e1xo/) (you should stretch the result window a bit to let it have enough width to see the results you wanted )

Comment: Corrected it but still.. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems fine when i run it on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the divs `<div id="newsImg">` , `<div class="metaNews">` using a `div` and set its `display` as `flex`.

```css
#newsBox {
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0.5rem auto;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: #333 solid 1px;
  background-color: #c2c2c2;
}

#newsImgWrapper {
  display: flex;
}

#newsImg {
  display: inline-block;
}

#newsImg>img {
  max-width: 120px;
  max-height: 120px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.metaNews {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

#newsTitle h3{ margin:0;}

.newsBy {
  display: inline-block;
}

.newsLink {
  float: right;
  width: 6rem;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #2F4F4F;
}

.newsLink a {
  font-family: 'Play', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="newsBox">
  <div id="newsImgWrapper">
    <div id="newsImg">
      <img src="images/news1.jpg" alt="news1">
    </div>

    <div class="metaNews">
      <div id="newsTitle">
        <h3>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text .</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="newsBrief">
        <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>

  <div class="newsBy">
    <span class="metaDate">Posted on 10/5/2017</span>
    <span class="metaBy">By Li</span>
  </div>

  <div class="newsLink">
    <a href="news1.html">View &rarr;</a>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: The problem with that is that it puts every block in a single line, even the second ones "newsBy" and "newsLink". Why? Also, thank you a lot for answering.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `display: inline-block`, Without use width, `display: inline-block` does not work without using setting width,

So I added these properties: `width: 50%` to `#newsImg` selector and to `.metaNews`,

Here a running example in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4x3vw0z4/4/)

Comment: I've tried that and it worked but there are gaps between image and at the upper side of the image. Can i fix that? Also, why do we need to set width? Can't they work in  a fixed set? Thank you a lot for answering back.

Comment: Image position is down cause of the vertical alignment, I added this property `vertical-align: top` to `#newsImg` selector, And for the question it's need width cause `inline-block` property needs width cause it's block, else you can use just `inline` property, And it will work without specifying width.
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4x3vw0z4/6/)